# Android Studio Imported project shows different user in SDK Directory

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just installed android studio and imported a sample project but I'm receiving an SDK Directory path not found error. How can i modify this? I tried changing the SDK path in **Open Module Settings > SDKs > Android API 26 Platform** but still nothing changed

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The SDK directory 'C:\Users\(MY USER)\Documents\Code Base v1\cerberus-android\Users\(ORIGINAL USER)\Library\Android\sdk' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few notes**

The sample project you have downloaded included the personal copy of his/her `local.properties` file which is incorrect. This file should be ignored in a version control system and the user of the project should have his/her own copy of it.

**What you can do**

If you are using Windows OS:

Go to `local.properties` file:

Change the line

```
sdk.dir='C:\Users\(MY USER)\Documents\Code Base v1\cerberus-android\Users\(ORIGINAL USER)\Library\Android\sdk'
```

To

```
sdk.dir=C:\Users\PATH\TO\YOUR\SDK
```

Otherwise, if you are on Mac OS:

Change it to

```
sdk.dir=/PATH/TO/YOUR/SDK

// or

sdk.dir=/Users/(YOUR_USERNAME)/Library/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `skd.dir` variable inside the `local.properties` file.